# How does a break function in the inner loop in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, break

```
while (statement 1){
  ......
  ......
  if (statement 2){
    x <- x + 1
    break
  }
  if (statement 3){
    y <- y + 1
  }
}
```

I have a pseudocode as shown above, I want to verify my understanding whether is correct or not. Is it when the `statement 2` is fulfilled, the equation in the 1st `if loop` will still run, then it will break the `if loop`and never come back again even the `while loop` still continue going on?

I am seeking an explanation about the break function in this scenario.

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply test this?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how should I test this, any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify how it works with this simple example :

```
num <- 2
x <- 0
y<- 0

while (TRUE){
   if (num %% 10 == 0){
     cat('\nprinting from 1: ', num)
      x <- x + 1
      break
    }
   if (num %% 2 == 0){
     cat('\nprinting from 2: ', num)
     y <- y+ 1
   }
   num <- num + 1
}


#printing from 2:  2
#printing from 2:  4
#printing from 2:  6
#printing from 2:  8
#printing from 1:  10

x
#[1] 1
y
#[1] 4
```

`while(TRUE)` makes it run for an infinite time. Every time `num` is divisible by 2 `y` is incremented and when `num` is divisible by 10 it increments `y` and the `while` loop breaks.

Comment: By the way, if I have a `for` loop, `for(i in 1:1000)` outside the `while` loop for iteration purpose, once the `while` loop breaks it will start the 2nd iteration, `i=2`?

Comment: No, it will not break the `for` loop. It will only break one level i.e `while` loop.

Comment: So which means the iteration is still in `i=1` but is the 2nd time for the `while loop`?

Comment: It depends on how you write the `while` loop but usually, it would just complete all the commands which are there outside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

In short, `break` stops the loop at the exact position you write it without running any of the following code. You can test this by writing some easy statements and defining `x` and `y`. `message` is a useful function here as you can verify which part of the code still runs.

```
x <- 1
y <- 1

while (x < 100){
  if (x == 1){
    x <- x + 1
    break
  }
  message(x)
  if (y < 100){
    y <- y + 1
  }
  message(y)
}
```

In this example, the first run is already interrupted as `x == 1` is true from the beginning. You will notice that no message is printed but the value for `x` is 2 now.

In the second example, I made up a statement which will become true after a few iterations. Messages with the value of `x` and `y` are now printed for each iteration but once `y > 10` nothing is printed and the loop stops immediately.

```
x <- 1
y <- 1

while (x < 100){
  if (y > 10){
    x <- x + 1
    break
  }
  message(x)
  if (y < 100){
    y <- y + 1
  }
  message(y)
}
```

The difference of `break` in comparison to `stop` for example is that it will only interrupt the inner-most loop (and that `stop` prints a stop/error message). Meaning that if your code sits in another loop, that outer loop will continue. For example:

```
for (x in 1:10) {
  y <- 1
  while (x < 100){
    if (y > 10){
      x <- x + 1
      break
    }
    message(x)
    if (y < 100){
      y <- y + 1
    }
    message(y)
  }
}
```